# Error when external content, not when inline

Tags: jquery, initialization

I am obviously overlooking something

I have firebugged it to death and give up

I am implementing a sticky bottom bar using [dynamic drive stickybar](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/stickybar.htm) script that seems to do all I want except setting a cookie to remember the state. If I keep the bar content inline it works as advertised, but when I externalise the content, I get
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined`
which looks like the content has not loaded by the time it is accessed by the script.

In FireFox I get

```
TypeError: this.setting is undefined
/SO/expstickybar/expstickybar2.js
Line 47
```

Can someone please help me identify where the issue lies? It would be helpful for future debugging sessions to be able to figure out where it goes wrong.

1. [page with inline content that works](http://plungjan.name/SO/expstickybar/cookie.htm)
2. [page with external content that does NOT work](http://plungjan.name/SO/expstickybar/cookie1.htm)
3. [page with external content appended directly to page also does not work](http://plungjan.name/SO/expstickybar/cookie2.htm)

**UPDATE** started from scratch and fixed it here [DEMO](http://plungjan.name/SO/expstickybar/ddorg.htm)

I assume some generic jQuery issue I need to learn about for future reference, so I hope someone will help instead of closing it as too localized.

Answer (score 2):

Your example of content with external content doesn't have a div named `stickybar`

From the page that doesn't work :

```
<div id="ajaxstickydiv_stickybar">
```

ANd from the page that does :

```
<div id="stickybar" class="expstickybar" style="visibility: visible; bottom: 0px;">
```

When your jQuery looks for div named `stickybar`, in the 1st example it doesn't find it and that's why the error.

```
var mystickybar=new expstickybar({
    id: "stickybar", //  <---- Problem here
      ...
});
```

});

**EDIT:**

I'm not sure, but in your external content the wrapper div has a duplicate id of `stickybar` which might cause the problem. Try renaming it.

Comment: But it does have a stickybar with id stickybar it is inside the ajaxstickydiv

Comment: Please see update. I have added a page that does NOT wrap in ajaxstickydiv

Comment: @mplungjan Try wrapping your code in `$(document).ready` and read my edit

Comment: It's wrapped in $(function) - where do you see the duplicate id="stickybar" ?

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. Started from scratch